# MMDrawerController keep center view controller completely visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mmdrawercontroller

I've got an MMDrawerController in the iPhone version of my app and I love it! I'm working on my iPad implementation now. I would like to keep the left drawer open all/most the time and use it sort of like a split view controller. (I'm not using a real split view controller because so many problems come along with those, I'm tired of fighting with them.) When the left drawer is open, however, the center view controller is just moved off to the side as normal.

Is there a way to configure the MMDrawerController so that the center view isn't pushed off to the side, but instead just sets a smaller width on the center controller so that it is still entirely visible on the screen?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Hi Are you able to do this task?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the drawer open all of the time, then simply subtract the drawer width from the centre view controller's view. Does that not work?

EDIT: So it seems that MMDrawerController uses its own centre view container. Instead of messing with internal library code, what you can do is use a dummy centre view controller. And then create a navigation controller with your actual centre view controller. Adjust the frame for the navigation view controller's view and add it as a child view controller to the dummy centre view controller.

The catch here is that every time you push a new view controller, you will have to adjust its frame to account for the side drawer's width.

Here's the link to the above in code: https://bitbucket.org/pallakgrewal/mmdrawersplitcontroller
Be sure to update

```
[self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
```

to MMCloseDrawerGestureModeNone in the app delegate.